# Call 'action' on HTML web form in a UIWebView

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to skip the login page of a website, so I can give the user a more aesthetically appealing login page, and save their login credentials for automatic login in the future. So far I have two UITextFields, and a UIButton. The user enters their username and password, and upon pressing the UIButton their details are entered into the actual webform on the sites login page, and the subsequent 'logged-in' page is shown in a UIWebView. The webView will be hidden while the app logs the user in, and then presented when the 'logged-in' page has loaded.

I've managed to populate the webform, but simply can't actually submit it! I'm sure there's a very simple solution!

This is the code I have so far, and if there's a better way I should be doing this let me know!

```
-(IBAction)login:(id)sender
{   
    // Create js strings    
    NSString *loadUsernameJS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var username = document.getElementsByName('username')[0]; username.value='%@';", username.text];
    NSString *loadPasswordJS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var password = document.getElementsByName('password')[0]; password.value='%@';", password.text];    

    // Autofill the form - this works, and I can see the values being put into the webform
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: loadUsernameJS];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: loadPasswordJS];

        // This is the method I have tried to submit the form, but nothing happens (ct100 is the ID of the form).

    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.ct100.submit();"];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below Approach might be helpful to you

```
 Put this code  inside the didFinishLoading Method Of UIWebView Protocol
```

**Fill The USerId**

```
 [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('username').value = 'userId'"];
```

**Fill The Password**

```
 [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('password').value = 'password'"];
```

**Call Submit Button as below**

```
    [webView 
stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.forms['login_form'].submit();"];
```

Here`login_form` is the Name of You Form

**Note:**  You have to manage one thing once you have filled the Credential clicked the Submit button. you need to make some BOOL or something else for avoiding the loading repetition of UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"ct100\").submit()"];
```

Your view controller needs to implement the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol and set itself as the UIWebView's `delegate`. Returning YES from `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest` (see code below) will allow the web view to navigate to any url the your form is submitting to.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSLog(@"Allow navigation to request = %@", request);
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sanjit, unfortunately still no luck! I'm not sure why this isn't working.

Comment: Have you implemented webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: in your UIWebViewDelegate implementation? You need to return YES for the specified request in order for the web view to navigate to the submit url.

Comment: I'm a little new to this, would you mind explaining in a bit more detail how'd I'd go about that for the specific request?

Comment: That's what I had done. The NSLog runs and prints the request when the page first loads (I have another NSLog in viewDidFinishLoad to tell me when it's finished loading. But then when I input the details and click my 'login' button nothing happens. There is no new request, which makes me think the document.getElementById(\"ct100\").submit() function isn't working. Is there a way I can test this? Thanks for all your help so far by the way!